# updating the datagridview in form1 with changes in form2

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

I have done for clicking one the datagridview row cell in one form say form 1 another form say form 2 will open along with selected data grid view data on form1..

I am using winforms...c#

i have done  some operations on  datagrid view data and at the end of the  operations stage the form2 will be closed

```
    NOTE :upto this i have  finished
```

i want to update the datagridview in form1 with changes i have done in form2

for that i have done like this..

form 1:

```
     private void productGridview_Cellclick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
     {

         if (e.ColumnIndex != productgridview.Columns["productimage"].Index) return;

            if (productgridview.SelectedCells.Count == 0) return;

            int selectedrowindex= productgridview.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;

            DataGridViewRow selectedRow = productgridview.Rows[selectedrowindex];
              if (img is Image)
               {
                   using (ProductDescriptionForm pf = new ProductDescriptionForm())
                   {

                       pf.picture = img;
                       pf.productname = productname;
                       pf.description = desc;
                       pf.productprice = productprices;
                       pf.categoryname = categoryCombobox.Text;
                       pf.productid = productids;
                       pf.ShowDialog(this);
                   }
               }
      }
```

and in form2 : I have done like this ...

```
         public int productid
    {
        get { return _prodid; }
        set { _prodid = value; }

    }
    public Image picture
    {
        get { return pictureBox1.Image; } 
        set { pictureBox1.Image = value; }
    }
   like this  some constructors  i have used and then
```

i  have  deleted one row in datagridview by using below code ...its fine..

```
      private void btnProdDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        using(var context = new TsgEclipseEntities())
        {
              var pd = new product(){ product_Id = productid };
              context.products.Attach(pd);
              context.DeleteObject(pd);
              context.SaveChanges();
              this.Close();   // form2 close                   
       }

    }
```

now i want to update the datagridview in form1 how i have  to do that .....

can any one have idea about this ...

many thanks....

Comment: What is your datasource MS-SQL?

Comment: no my database is mysql i am retrieving the data using mysql work bench and i then i ahve connected the data to model.edmx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) write a databind method that accepts a product_id parameter to get data in form 1 
2) Before form2.close, intialize form 1 class, and call the method by passing the product_id you just updated and open form1.

Answer (score 0):

In Form1 create a BindingSource in Form1 use this a the Datasource for the Grid in Form1. Pass the same Binding source to Form2. Use this as the Datasource for your Grid in Form2.

The changes will be seamless.

Comment: i have defined productbindingsource in form1 do u mean   i  have to use this bindingsource in form2 if so ??? how do i any syntax pls..

Comment: i dont have any datagridview in form 2 .... for specifying bindingsource  in form2...

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood that you have another Grid in Form2.

Comment: You might want to use the BindingSource from Form1 to pass to Form2. In Form2, use the BindingSource.Current - this will give you the current row that you have selected in Form1's Grid. You can use this to Bind to the individual UI elements in Form2 in Form2's Load Event.

Comment: Syntax that you might want to use in Form2 would be: `<yourForm2sTextBox>.DataBindings.Add("Text", <yourBindingSource>, "<ColumnName>");`

Comment: i dint use the any binding source to pass values from form1 to form2 see my code i have just used constructors in form2 .. so how to pass the binding source from form1 to fomr2 .. would you pls elaborate ...

Comment: You can create a public property in Form2 of type BindingSource. From Form1, set this property in Form2 - you got to do that before you invoke ShowDialog() of Form2.

Comment: `public BindingSource myBinding {get; set;}`. From Form1, just set this property with Form1's BindingSource that you created. Also, you can remove any other property members (like productname, etc) that you have defined in Form2 - let Form2 deal with these using BindingSource.

Comment: if i remove all how do represent the row values in textboxes in form 2

Comment: Like I said, if you use the Binding Syntax that was provided before it would handle the wiring (representing the value and updating back) automatically. I would typically add the Binding in the Load event of Form2: `yourForm2sTextBox>.DataBindings.Add("Text", <yourBindingSource>, "<ColumnName>");`

Answer (score 0):

In your Form2 btnProdDelete_Click event before you close the form Set your DialogResult to OK - this.DialogResult = OK;
In your using ProductDescriptionForm pf - after you show the dialog - see if the Result is OK if they hit the X it is cancel,
After ShowDialog you will now be able to access the public property productid
 and  you can do what you want in form 1 with that productid, you need not create an instance of form 1 - it just happens like magic.

[A quick easy example of passing data from form2 to form 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29096073/pass-value-from-form2-listview-to-form1-datagridview)

Comment: Please improve your answer formatting a bit more the text.