# Refresh user control in form:1 on form:2 closing event in winforms C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Form:1 contains a user control, on the cell click event of the user control grid I show form:2. When I update values in form:2 and close it, the user control grid in form:1 should get refreshed. 
I did the same as in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124337/updating-the-datagridview-in-form1-with-changes-in-form2) though it does not produce any error, the user control grid did not get bind!!!

Please let me know how this can be accomplished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented this functionality using delegates,

Declare delegate in user control,

```
public delegate void Delegate1(datatype param1,datatype param2, datatype param3);//should be similar to the method used to bind user control in form1
public Delegate1 RefreshGrid;
```

In cell click event of user control, after form2.ShowDialog()add

```
RefreshGrid(param1,param2,param3);
```

In form1's constructor after intializecomponent() method add

```
usercontrolID.RefreshGrid = MethodUsedToBindUserControl;
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the advantage of [ShowDialog() method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/39wcs2dh%28VS.80%29.aspx).

If a form is displayed as modal, the code following the ShowDialog method is not executed until the dialog box is closed. However, when a form is shown as modeless, the code following the Show method is executed immediately after the form is displayed.

```
private void CellClicked()
{
   Form2 form2 = new Form2();
   form2.ShowDialog();
   //Execution stops here until you close the form2.

   myForm1Control.Values = form2.GetValues();

}
```

Comment: The one thing I might add is have the first line be `using(Form2 form2 = new Form2())` and put the `ShowDialog` and `.Values = ...` lines inside the using call so that the form is disposed.

Comment: On cell click event of user control form:2 is shown. In which event should I call this method?

Comment: @phsr : I agreed, that's a better way to do.

Comment: @banupriya: This should be in your cell click event I think. Do you understand how ShowDialog stops the execution until you close Form2