# Pass Value from Form2 ListView to Form1 DataGridView

Tags: c#, listview, datagridview, lookup

I've 2 forms in C# Application, Form1 is main form containing DataGridView, columns are AccountCode, AccountName, Amount, Narration. At present user can enter AccountCode manually and using Sql query AccountName is populated with relevant title.

Now I am looking for a way to that user will search AccountCode in Form2 containing ListView holding AccountCodes and AccountName, after user DoubleClick or press OK button return selected value to Active row in Form1 DataGridView. Active Row is the main concern here, because look up Form2 will not only be used to enter new record but also to update other records which also require look up values from Form2 ListView.

I know how to pass values between Form2 ListView to Form1 TextBoxes using delegates, but don't know how to pass it to DataGridView's Active Row.

Seeking for expert guidance/advices

Ahmed

Comment: after passing values you have to fire event at form2 load

Comment: @utility form2 is lookup form, Form1 is the main form with DataGridView, data need to pass from Form2 to Form1

Comment: form1 should get triggered to refresh itself else you cannot pass value using a form lookup

Comment: @utility the problem is how do I do pass values from Form2 ListView to Form1 DataGridView's Active row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the Form2 you can create public property and set value to that according to your logic

```
 public string SelectedCode { get; set; }
```

and in Form1 you can access that public property and set value to datagrid for example

```
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
        frm2.ShowDialog(this);
        dataGridView1.SelectedCells[0].Value = frm2.SelectedCode;
```

Comment: this is at the same time both simple and amazing, thanks for your answer..Just SelectedCell don't work for me, I replace it with CurrentRow and use Column Name property to set values...Thanks a lot